# Network GKE cluster between VPC subnets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56928585/how-a-private-clusters-in-gke-authenticates-the-gcp-compute-instances-vms-in-t), the author says that the gke cluster is not available from other subnets in the VPC.

BUT, that is exactly what I need to do. I've added detail below, all suggestions welcome.

I created a VPC in Google Cloud with custom sub-nets. I have a subnet in us-east1 and another in us-east4. Then, I created a VPC-native private GKE cluster in the same VPC in the us-east4 subnet.

[added details]
GKE in us-east4
endpoint 10.181.15.2
control plane 10.181.15.0/28
pod address range 10.16.0.0/16
service address range 10.17.0.0/22

VPC subnet in us-east4
10.181.11.0/24

VPC subnet in us-east1
10.171.1.0/24

I added 10.171.1.0/24 as a Control Plane authorized network, and I added 10.171.1.0/24 to the automatically created firewall rule.

But I still can't use kubectl from the instance in the 10.171.1.0/24 subnet.

What I see when trying to use kubectl from a VM in us-east4 10.181.11.7

On this VM, I set the context with `kubectl config use-context <correct gke context>` and I have gcloud configured correctly. Then,
`kubectl get pods` correctly gives a list of pods in the gke cluster.

from a VM in us-east4 10.171.1.0 subnet, which is set up in the same way, `kubectl get pods` times out with an error that it's unable to reach the endpoint. The message is:

```
kubectl get pods
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 10.181.15.2:443: i/o timeout
```

This seems like a firewall problem, but I've been unable to find a solution, despite the abundance of GKE documentation out there. It could be a routing problem, but I thought VPC-native GKE cluster would take care of the routes automatically?

Comment: Have you try to add the IP range from us-east4 10.181.11.0/24 in the control plane? You can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/authorized-networks#add) fro more information.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the private endpoint for the control plane is accessible from clients in the same region as the cluster.  If you want clients in the same VPC but located in [different regions to access the control plane](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#cp-global-access), you'll need to enable global access using the `--enable-master-global-access` option. You can do this when you create the cluster or you can update an existing cluster.

Comment: Thank you! this was the answer that worked in my case. Once access was enabled, I was able to use `kubectl get nodes` without any timeouts or errors.